# NoMethodError with user path for nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting following error :

```
undefined method `recommendations_path' for  #<#<Class:0x0078>>
```

I have Recommendation model

```
class Recommendation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :recommended_user, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :recommended_user_id
end
```

I have user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :recommendations
   ................
end
```

In recommendation controller

```
def new
    @recommendation = current_user.recommendations.new
end
```

In new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @recommendation do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :relationship %>
    <%= f.text_field :comment %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

My routes, where I think problem is:

```
  devise_for :users
  resources :users, only: [:show] do
    collection do
      get :customer_signup
      get :employee_signup
    end
    member do
      get :choose_role
      get :become_a_customer
      get :become_a_employee
    end
  end

  resources :users do
    resources :recommendations
  end
```

Comment: You need user_recommendations_path. Have you tried running rake:routes to see the routes available in your app?

Comment: @NickM That should be automatically generated by f.submit right ?

Comment: Actually @Uzbekjon has the correct answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats actually when the form is trying to identify the path for your `@recommendation`.

According to your `routes.rb` your form must be:

```
<%= form_for [:user, @recommendation] do |f| %>
```

Comment: That should be [:user, @recommendation] but it worked Thanks!

Comment: Actually, that should be `[@user, @recommendation]`. Isn't it?

Comment: [:user, @recommendation] is working fine, without even fetching @user = current_user

Comment: please edit your answer so that i can mark it correct.